# Интерфейс программы. После форматирования из .ui в .py не выводит в конце код main для кода всем программы |PyQt \ pyside2\ Python\ qt designer\

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]во всех гайдах после форматирования .ui в .py должен выйти в конце код , кторый нужно скопировать и вставить в другой код, но у меня его нет, почему, и что сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно в последних версиях его попросту убрали. Сколько пользовался Qt Designer, сам его все время писал.

Comment: как самому написать?

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста модуль `.ui`. Покажите как вы преобразовываете `.ui` в `.py`

Comment: через cmd:     C:\Users\user>pyside2-uic "D:\Python\intr1.ui" -o "D:\Python\intrfeis1.py"

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `-x`, т.е. `pyside2-uic "D:\Python\intr1.ui" -o "D:\Python\intrfeis1.py" -x`

Comment: Он не опознает опцию -x , в видео его тоже используют, но работает только без него , но нет в конце кода. Как самому его написать - я не знаю. Либо скачивать старый питон как-то наверное.